# WordPress - Cron job not executed

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm having some problems to schedule a custom cron job in a wordpress plugin.
I have this code inside my class and is supposed to send multiple emails to different adresses and each email will have a different subject and message.

```php
class GreetingTicketScheduler {   

    public function __construct()
    {
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, [$this, 'schedule_orders_forward']);
        add_action('forward_orders', [$this, 'send_confirmed_orders']);

    }

    public function schedule_orders_forward()
    {
        // Schedules the event if it's NOT already scheduled.
        if(!wp_next_scheduled('forward_orders')){
            wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'send_confirmed_orders', [], true);
        }
    }

    public function send_confirmed_orders()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'order_codes';
        //
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
        //
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
        //
        if( !empty($results) ){
            //
            $pdv_subject = "Morning greetings of " . date('d-m-Y', time());
            //
            $pdv_message_a .= "Salut!\n";

            $pdv_email_a = 'mail.example@example.org';
            $pdv_headers_a[] = 'Cc: mail.example@example.org';

            //
            $pdv_message_b .= "Ciao!\n";

            $pdv_email_b = 'mail.example@example.org';
            $pdv_headers_b[] = 'Cc: mail.example@example.org';
            
            //
            $pdv_message_p .= "Hi!\n";

            $pdv_email_p = 'mail.example@example.org';
            $pdv_headers_p[] = 'Cc: mail.example@example.org';


            //
            foreach( $results as $key => $val ){
                if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time()) && $val['order_cpco'] === '6605'){
                    $pdv_message_a .= $val['order_file'] . "\n";
                } 
                //
                if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time()) && $val['order_cpco'] === '6200'){
                    $pdv_message_b .= $val['order_file'] . "\n";
                }
                // 
                if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time()) && $val['order_cpco'] === '6600' ){
                    $pdv_message_p .= $val['order_file'] . "\n";
                }
            }            
            //
            //wp_mail( $to:string|array, $subject:string, $message:string, $headers:string|array, $attachments:string|array )
            //
            wp_mail($pdv_email_a, $pdv_subject, $pdv_message_a, $pdv_headers_a);
            //
            wp_mail($pdv_email_b, $pdv_subject, $pdv_message_b, $pdv_headers_b);
            //
            wp_mail($pdv_email_p, $pdv_subject, $pdv_message_p, $pdv_headaers_p);

        }        
    }
}
```

In my staging envoirment I have the plugin activated but I've noticed that the emails will be not send, probably I've missed something in the code.

What I need to modify to correctly schedule the cron job every five minutes or every hour?

Comment: _"but I've noticed that the emails will be not send"_ - that _could_be a different problem altogether, you should first of all verify whether your function did actually get executed, or not.

Comment: Are you using this with a _real_ cron, or only WP's default "cron" implementation that needs page visits to actually trigger?

Comment: @CBroe I'm using the WP way to do cron because I don't have access to the system scheduler on my shared hosting space. What I mean for the email will be not send is that the cron will be not fired. I'm on an headless theme, can be this the cause?

Comment: Third parameter for wp_schedule_event should be the action hook. Not a method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an action hook to schedule the cron job, and then call the function.

```
class GreetingTicketScheduler {   

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp', [$this, 'schedule_orders_forward']);
        add_action('forward_orders', [$this, 'send_confirmed_orders']);
    }

    public function schedule_orders_forward()
    {
        if (!wp_next_scheduled('forward_orders')) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'forward_orders');
        }
    }

    public function send_confirmed_orders()
    {
        // ... code to send emails ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the `wp` hook and what will change from `register_activation_hook` that I've used?

Comment: just update the line , i hope that will helpfull - wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'forward_orders', [], true);

Comment: I've tested with the hook you've suggested but seems that the cron job isn't executed

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: As you've suggested I've replaced the `register_activation_hook` with the `add_action('wp', ...)` but the cron will be not fired and not registered if I try looking for it using `wp_get_scheduled_event()` function

Comment: **wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'forward_orders', [], true);**

Comment: ok, didn't saw that I need to pass the event instead of the function. Thank you for the help

Comment: to add a 5min cron, I need to add it to the wordpress default scheduled cron right?

Comment: @ICTDEV yes, you should use like this - wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'forward_orders', [], true);

Comment: And make sure the function (  forward_orders ) is in the action hook. Thanks 